# Regular expression can't match the whole Bengali word

Tags: php, regex, hashtag, bengali

I'm trying to use regular expression to match hashtags. When the language of a hashtag is English or Chinese, my code works fine. But when the language is Bengali, my code can't match the whole Bengali word.

Here is the code I'm testing with:

```php
<?php

$hashtag = '#আয়াতুল_কুরসি';

preg_match('/(#\w+)/u', $hashtag, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

And the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => #আয়
    [1] => #আয়
)
```

I tried changing the pattern to `'/(#\p{L}+)/u'`, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is that `\w` here does not match all diacritics that Bengali characters may contain. You need to allow them all:

```php
preg_match('/#[\w\p{M}]+/u', $hashtag, $matches);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/o0Zdm).